# Can't validate and display errors in PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, session

I am trying to display form information with Shipping Information Heading, with validation of name, contact etc. I am able to display it but not able to validate it and if I submit a form blank it shows blank values except payment and shipping method are displaying with default values selected and one more thing it is not showing errors i.e; fname is required, I am confused a little bit. Can anyone add one things that if anyone post blank form it redirect it to again to form2.php page?

This is my form2.php page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="welcome2.php" method="post">


        <label>First name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
        <label>Lastname name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input type="email" name="email"><br>
        <label>Contact No </label>
        <input type="text" name="cno"><br>
        <label>Address </label>
        <input type="text" name="addr"><br>
        <label>City </label>
        <input type="text" name="city"><br>
        <label>State </label>
        <input type="text" name="state"><br>
        <label>Country </label>
        <input type="text" name="country"><br>
        <label>Zip Code </label>
        <input type="text" name="zipcode"><br>
        <label>Credit Card Number </label>
        <input type="text" name="ccno"><br>
        <label>Payment Option </label>
        <select name="Payment_option">
    <option value="Cash On Delivery">Cash On Delivery</option>
    <option value="Online">Online</option>
  </select> <br>
  <label>Shipping Method </label>
        <select name="Shipping_Method">
    <option value="TCS">TCS</option>
    <option value="Leapord">Leapord</option>
    <option value="FEDEX">FEDEX</option>
  </select> <br>
        <button type="submit" name="sub">Submit</button>

    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['errors']))
    {
        foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $key => $error)
        {
            echo $error."<br>";
        }
        unset($_SESSION['errors']);
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my welcome2.php page

```
    <?php  session_start();
    $fname = "";
    $lname = "";
    $email = "";
    $cno = "";
    $addr = "";
    $city = "";
    $state = "";
    $country = "";
    $zipcode = "";
    $ccno = "";
    extract($_POST);
    $errors = array();
    if(isset($_POST['fname'])){
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
    }if(isset($_POST['lname'])){
        $_SESSION['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];
    }if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    }if(isset($_POST['cno'])){
        $_SESSION['cno'] = $_POST['cno'];
    }if(isset($_POST['addr'])){
        $_SESSION['addr'] = $_POST['addr'];
    }if(isset($_POST['city'])){
        $_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];
    }if(isset($_POST['state'])){
        $_SESSION['state'] = $_POST['state'];
    }if(isset($_POST['country'])){
        $_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'];
    }if(isset($_POST['zipcode'])){
        $_SESSION['zipcode'] = $_POST['zipcode'];
    }if(isset($_POST['ccno'])){
        $_SESSION['ccno'] = $_POST['ccno'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {

    if(!$fname)
        $errors[] = "First name is required";
    }

    if(!$lname)
    {
        $errors[] = "Last name is required";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $errors = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname)) {
      $errors = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
    if(!$email)
    {
        $errors[] = "Email is required";
    }
    if(!$cno)
    {
        $errors[] = "Contact  is required";
    }if (strlen($cno)<=5)
    {
        $errors[] ="Contact contain more than 11 characters";
    }
    if(!$addr)
    {
        $errors[] = "Address is required";
    }
    if(!$city)
    {
        $errors[] = "City is required";
    }
    if(!$state)
    {
        $errors[] = "State is required";
    }
    if(!$country)
    {
        $errors[] = "Country is required";
    }
    if(!$zipcode)
    {
        $errors[] = "Zip Code is required";
    }
    if(!$ccno)
    {
        $errors[] = "Credit Card Number is required";
    }?>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Shipping Information </h1>
<?php   echo $fname; echo "<br>";
    echo $lname; echo "<br>";
     echo $email; echo "<br>";
     echo $cno; echo "<br>";
    echo $addr; echo "<br>";
    echo $city; echo "<br>";
    echo $state; echo "<br>";
    echo $country; echo "<br>";
     echo $zipcode; echo "<br>";
     echo $ccno; echo "<br>";
    $option1 = isset($_POST['Payment_option']) ? $_POST['Payment_option'] : false;
   if ($option1) {
      echo htmlentities($_POST['Payment_option'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
   } else {
     echo "Payment Method is required";
   } echo "<br>";
   $option2 = isset($_POST['Shipping_Method']) ? $_POST['Shipping_Method'] : false;
   if ($option2) {
      echo htmlentities($_POST['Shipping_Method'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
   } else {
     echo "Shipping Method is required";
   }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the values at the top of the PHP file, so they are always set. Then the errors never trigger because you do not check if the `$_POST[<value>]` is set and then assign it to the variable.

Also, try to use loops. It helps with code maintenance and readability. Something like this could work for you:

```
$values = [
'fname'     =>  'First Name',
'lname'     =>  'Last Name',
'email'     =>  'Email',
'test'      =>  'testt',
];
$results = array();
$errors = array();
foreach ( $values as $name => $displayName ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST[ $name ] ) )
    {
        $results[ $name ] = $_POST[ $name ];
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = $displayName . ' is required';
    }
}
```

Comment: @SyedKhizer are you getting all the form data and displaying the errors correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are being added with a faulty check. Use `empty($variable)` instead of the NOT operator (!).

Also, be careful how you are changing the value of your original empty variables.. I would use `extract( $_POST, EXTR_OVERWRITE, 'form_' );` to be even safer and then reference by $form_fname, etc. Then use the empty() check.

I also recommend using a debugger that can step through each line with you. It works wonders.